# VBA convert string to date format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a file with strings that are in the format YYMMDD. eg. 120216 (will always be in this format).

I want to convert this into a date ideally in the format DDMMYY or DDMMYYYY.

Has anyone come across a similar problem and how did they resolve it?

Comment: If you are going to down vote at least contribute to the thread. FYI the below answer did not work 100% to my scenario I still had to make some adjustments and it involved quite a few little hacks

Comment: So what code did you try first - its pretty clear why this was downvoted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split the string and then use `DateSerial`. See this example.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim sDate As String
    Dim Y As Long, M As Long, D As Long

    sDate = "120216"
    Y = Left(sDate, 2)
    M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
    D = Right(sDate, 2)

    Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), "DDMMYY")
    Debug.Print Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), "DDMMYYYY")
End Sub
```

**Followup from comments**

> Thanks, I am probably going to have to write up a function where I can pass in string dates to get converted. Any chance that the Debug... line be saved into a variable? (can't seem to) or an alternative work around? – Marco Susilo 4 mins ago

I have not done any error handling. I am sure you can take care of that?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim Ret As String

    Ret = GetDate("120216", "DDMMYY")

    Debug.Print Ret

    Ret = GetDate("120216", "DDMMYYYY")

    Debug.Print Ret
End Sub

Function GetDate(sDate As String, sFormat As String) As String
    Dim Y As Long, M As Long, D As Long

    Y = Left(sDate, 2)
    M = Mid(sDate, 3, 2)
    D = Right(sDate, 2)

    GetDate = Format(DateSerial(Y, M, D), sFormat)
End Function
```

Comment: @andyholaday: Cheers! Fixed it :)

Comment: Thanks, 
I am probably going to have to write up a function where I can pass in string dates to get converted. Any chance that the Debug... line be saved into a variable? (can't seem to) or an alternative work around?

Comment: @MarcoSusilo: Yes. See the updated post. You may have to refresh the page.